# wkhtmltopdf include stylesheet, how to?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using WKHTMLTOPDF in NodeJS, this creates a PDF(out.pdf),

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf'); 
wkhtmltopdf.command = 'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe';
wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>', {output: 'out.pdf'});
```

The above code works, now I would like to include a CSS stylesheet file, that will change the h1, p and upcoming div's.

This is coded in Javascript with NodeJS.

How can I include stylesheets which will cover the style from div's and elements inside the PDF?

Comment: set stylesheet's media to `print`. i.e.: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">` and write the style you want in `print.css`.

Comment: or, just simply,append `<style media="print">h1{color: skyblue;}</style>` in the html.

Comment: bitsMix, this does not seem to solve the problem. When I put  wkhtmltopdf('<h1 style='color:blue;'>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>', {output: 'out.pdf'}); it will work. But I'd like to include a complete stylesheet.  Have any other suggestions?